# Change default site in Sharepoint foundation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

my SP2010 site by defaul goes to: xxx.xx.x.xxx:xxxx/SitePages/Inicio.aspx now i need the main site is: xxx.xx.x.xxx:xxxx/Publico/default.aspx any idea plz?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If Publico is a Document library (or a module you have added) then it's easy.

Using SharePoint Designer

1. Open the site using SPD
2. Click All Files (at the bottom of Navigation)
3. Click your Document library/Module (Publico)
4. Right click the aspx page you want as default
5. Select Set as Home Page

Or in PowerShell use:

```
$w = Get-SPWeb http://xxx.xx.x.xxx:xxxx
$root = $w.RootFolder
$root.WelcomePage = "publico/default.aspx"
$root.Update()
```

But if Publico is a subsite or even separate site collection then you need some more work:

1. Add a redirect.aspx like this to a document library in the root site:

   <html>
   <head>
       <title>Redirect Page</title>
       <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://xxx.xx.x.xxx:xxxx/Publico/default.aspx" />
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
   </html>
2. Use the above method to set the redirect.aspx as WelcomePage for the root site

Comment: It's working I had the second case. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.