# Immediate Redirect page in sharepoint

Tags: publishing-page, redirect

I want to redirect a sites homepage to a subsites homepage. I can create a page from redirect page layout BUT, i want no waiting for a couple of seconds, i want immediate redirect. How can i achieve this?

Comment: My experience is that the Redirect layout is immediate for end users who do not have edit rights to the page. Is this not the case?

Comment: What access rights do you have? Are you an end user with edit privleges? Do you have access to the farm's server? Or somewhere in between?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It could be achieved with [HTTP Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525695%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in [IIS](http://www.iis.net/) using  [IIS URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) module. This module allows to create various rule actions including *redirect and request abort*.

For your scenario i recommend this option because *this should redirect the request **faster** as the redirection happens as soon as the HTTP request received by IIS*.

---

### Configuration

Let's describe how to configure Rule that *redirect a sites homepage to a subsites homepage* in URL Rewrite.

For example to redirect request from:

> http://{ServerName}/teamsite/SitePages/Home.aspx

to:

> http://{ServerName}/teamsite/itdepteamsite/SitePages/Home.aspx

the following Rule is used

[image]

,where

Pattern: `^(.*/)?teamsite/SitePages/home.aspx$`

Redirect URL: `teamsite/itdepteamsite/SitePages/Home.aspx`

Comment: Where do I find this setting? How would I go about adding these settings?

Comment: +1 for server redirect as the request cannot be handled any sooner.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a standard HTML redirect with a wait period of 0:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Redirecting...</title>
    <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.yoururl.com">
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Changing the value of `x` in `content="x;url"` determines the number of seconds to wait before redirecting.

See: [Redirect default.aspx or change default landing to page in _layouts folder?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31804/redirect-default-aspx-or-change-default-landing-to-page-in-layouts-folder)

and [Change default site in Sharepoint foundation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31786/change-default-site-in-sharepoint-foundation)

Comment: this solution is not suitable for my case, because i will do set this redirection on any subsites created automatically.

Comment: @rjcup3 fyi I just flagged your comment

Answer (score 3):

> this solution is not suitable for my case, because i will do set this redirection on any subsites created automatically.

Only one way to go then. You'll have to create an EventReciever which will trigger on WebProvisioned. The code will run every time a new subsite is created. You can find quiet a lot of information regarding this on Google.

**Update**

```
public override void WebProvisioned(SPWebEventProperties properties)
{
    SPWeb currentWeb = properties.Web;
    if (PublishingWeb.IsPublishingWeb(currentWeb))
    {
        PublishingWeb pubWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(currentWeb);
        //Get the file name
        SPFile welcomeFile = currentWeb.GetFile(pageName);
        //Assign the new filename to the DefaultPage property
        pubWeb.DefaultPage = welcomeFile;
        //Update the Publishing Web.
        pubWeb.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, that was really helping. and what to do in webprovisioned event?

Comment: @ozdogan Please check my updated answer.

Comment: thanks. and something more, what will be the myhomepage.aspx ? is it a page created from "redirect page layout" or some aspx file containing the redirection html tags?

Comment: @ozdogan I'd say a Redirect Page Layout" as they are ment for that purpose :)

Comment: thanks but you miss something. i want immediate redirection. in redirect page layout, it waits for 5 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can change the Welcome page to subsite homepage. To do this Go to Site Settings > Look and Feel -> Welcome Page

Comment: Which can also be set [using PowerShell](http://blog.hand-net.com/sharepoint/2012-06-08-feature-pour-definir-la-page-daccueil-dun-site.htm) : `(get-spweb http://yourwebapp).RootFolder.Properties["vti_welcomepage"]`, or from SharePoint Designer.

Comment: this solution is not suitable for my case, because i will do set this redirection on any subsites created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Another cool solution I found is this:

[Changing the Timeout Value for a SharePoint Redirect Page](http://blogs.c5insight.com/Home/entryid/359/Quick-Tip-Changing-the-Timeout-Value-for-a-SharePoint-Redirect-Page)

Short: Make a copy of the Redirect Page Layout and change the "SecondsBeforeRedirect" attribute from 5 to 0 in the source code

```
<PublishingWebControls:RedirectControl SecondsBeforeRedirect="0" runat="server"/>
```

This solution also has a latency time sadly