# Redirect sharepoint page to external site in IIS

Tags: redirect

I'm trying to redirect to from a web page in sharepoint site to another page. I want once the users go to this page /pages/voice.aspx it should redirect them to google home page. This is my code: I'm using IIS Rewrite Module

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="test" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" negate="false" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.google.com" appendQueryString="false" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="/Pages/Voice.aspx" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

then when I access the page, it wont redirect to google home page and no error message was shown on screen.

If there's an alternative way to do the same, please share. 
I have followed the same steps in this answer but still no luck [Immediate Redirect page in sharepoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/51604/immediate-redirect-page-in-sharepoint)

I also have tried

```
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.yoururl.com">
```

but it doesnt redirect, the page remains the same.

I have used 'Redirect' page template in sharepoint but I think its slow for the end user as it needs 5 seconds. I want something instant.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding a Content Editor Web part to the page you want to redirect from, and add the following piece to it. Just tested it on my page and it worked.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://google.com"/>
```

Comment: On my page it doesn't work, I'm not sure why.

Comment: Because ``meta`` tags have to be in the HEAD of an HTML document, and your CEWP places content in the BODY... Look for JavaScript ``document.location`` usage

Comment: Maybe put the code in a text file.  Then point the CWEP to that file.  Prevents SharePoint from modifying the code.

Comment: Can't I have something like non existing page for example: `domain/voice` and when the user access that page, instead of giving not found, it'd redirect to a link `google.com`