# Change SharePoint default website language

Tags: sharepoint-online

Our public facing website has developed in sp 2013.

We have a cross site publishing to manage the content and all.
The site is in 2 different languages i.e English and Arabic.

By default whenever end user enter our site url the site will start in Arabic language, but sometimes we have some problems with the Arabic version,
so for those kind of situations we immediately want to make English site as our default website.

Example:

Urls for our website is like:

```
Website.com
```

It automatically get the url like

```
website.com/sites/ar....
```

If anyone selects English language from home page of Arabic, the url changes to

```
website.com/sites/en....
```

I want to make `website.com/sites/en` as default website.

May I please know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use URL rewrite functionality of IIS,.

Open IIS manager
Right click on your SharePoint website -> Properties
Go to tab Home Directory
Choose A redirection to a URL
fill the URL for redirection. for example: http://contoso.com/sites/official

[image]

Notes:

Make sure to check A Directory below URL entered to avoid redirect loop
Link to another thread might interest the reader - [immediate redirect page in sharepoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/51604/immediate-redirect-page-in-sharepoint?newreg=abbb93ea53c04f718d49b56abd1c08e6)

[Ref link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713391/how-to-redirect-root-web-site-to-site-collection)

Comment: Dear sir, Thank you so much for your response.
I will try and update you soon.