# Immediate Redirect page from root to communication site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, powershell, css, redirect

How do I redirect to a site collection in SPO without ANY lag? The root `https://******.sharepoint.com` now has a simple javascript redirect:
          `window.location.href = 'https://******.sharepoint.com/sites/home';`

The problem is there a delay. Even placing a redirect in the `<meta>` head area and setting it to zero still has a lag in the redirect:

```
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV=”REFRESH” content=”0”; url=”https://******.sharepoint.com/sites/Home”>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; ,URL=https://******.sharepoint.com/sites/Home">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='https://******.sharepoint.com/sites/Home'" />
```

this might be of interest: [immediate redirect IIS](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/51604/immediate-redirect-page-in-sharepoint)

The only other way I know to avoid a lag in the redirect is a Powershell script.

```
#Connect to the SharePoint Online Site
$Username = "Anupam.Shrivastava@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter your password" -AsSecureString
$Site = "https://myteant.sharepoint.com/sites/SC2"
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Site)
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username,$Password)
$Context.Credentials = $Creds
 
#Update the welcome page
$web = $Context.Web
$rootFolder = $web.RootFolder; 
$rootFolder.WelcomePage = "SitePages/New Home.aspx";
$rootFolder.Update();
$Context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was not working well because I made a modern page off the root classic site. I input a SPFX web part that loaded JS. This is too many moving parts...

An effective way to do this is to create a **classic page**. I created a **web part** classic page and placed the JavaScript in the top of the page. I found that the issue is the modern pages. The load time is much better for classic pages.

Make the homepage a classic page with  `window.location.href = 'https://******.sharepoint.com/sites/home';` and it should work fine.